# How can I call the "pushButton" in main.cpp?

Tags: qt

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            &a, SLOT(quit()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

All the codes are given above. In a general Qt GUI program, I put a pushButton on the UI Form and tried to use it in main.cpp. But below error was given:

```
main.cpp:10: Error:'pushButton' was not declared in this scope
```

Could you please give me a solution? How can I call it in main.cpp?
Thanks!

***Complement1***:

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            QCoreApplication::instance(), SLOT(close()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

If I do it this way, then the program can run but cannot close the whole application. I guess that is because the QCoreApplication::instance() returns null due to in the constructor phase the QApplication doesn't exist, right?

***Complement2***:

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    close();
}
```

One solution is to add new slot of the pushButton in mainwindow.cpp, like above.
But still I hope to know how to do it my way (main part of this post)?

***Complement3:***

Alberto's code works fine by using **QWidget** as below way.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
```

Comment: Why do you need to call it in main.cpp so badly?

Comment: Then how to do? I need to quit the whole application, but the 'a' points to the whole application is in main.cpp, so I put the code in it.

Comment: You can always retrieve a pointer to the current Q(Core)Application by calling the static QCoreApplication::instance() function, from anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please check my main post above, Complement1 part.

Comment: Why do you connect to a "close" SLOT? QCoreApp doesn't have that. What you're looking for is the "quit" SLOT. ([ref](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit))

Comment: Thank you! You are right. This way works fine! How can I give you *reputation* and close this post?

Comment: @TomXue read debug output for future. I'm 100% sure that on `QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            QCoreApplication::instance(), SLOT(close()));` call you got error message on console output about not existing slot

Comment: @TomXue just accept an answer below that is correct =)

Comment: I put the code here: https://github.com/tomxue/snippet_Qt_quit, and it really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach can't work because, as compiler says, you didn't defined a QPushButton in main.cpp scope. So compiler can't find it.

Right approach is your last one. You develop a .ui file in which you add a QPushButton and then in c++ code that handles your .ui file(in your example a QMainWindow subclass) you connect it with a slot. But your connect call is wrong. This is my code:

```
//widget.h:
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H

//widget.cpp:
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

#include <QtGui>

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close()));
}


//widget.ui:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Widget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Widget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>93</width>
    <height>41</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Widget</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>PushButton</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>


//main.cpp:
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

with: connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(close())); 
which we can simplify in this way: connect(1,2,3,4);

when 2 is emitted because user does something on 1, do 4 on 3.

translated: when user click on pushButton(defined into ui file), do close on this(QMainWindow subclass). And if you take a look at your main.cpp code, MainWindow is the main widget you show to the user. So you're closing the whole app.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works fine. But mine is very similiar to yours while it doesn't work the same way! I noticed the difference is that you use QWidget and I use QMainWindow.

Comment: QMainWindow and QWidget works in the same way. So it doesn't matter. Maybe you added/dropped something else. You could try use my code and add a QMainWindow instead of QWidget. Then tell us if you can't solve.

Comment: Sorry. I fotgot to update it. I did the trial again later and that time it worked fine, for both QWidget and QMainWindow. Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry. It has to work because QMainWindow inherits from QWidget. I forgot to mention it.